# Is it possible to occupy two states at the same time in Markov process/chain?

Tags: markov-process

As in the topic - is it possible for an agent in a system of Markov's fashion to move into two states at once?

Comment: Hi: By definition of a state, the answer is no. but you may be able re-define the states so that, by way of definition, the process can move into a state where that state captures the notion of two states.

Comment: This is exactly what I thought of. Any idea how to let know the system about the time spent in the merged/re-defined state?

Comment: Hi : maybe if you give more details on the example you're dealing with, it would be easier. of course, maybe not also :).